# meaning of (noun?)조차

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, korean-to-english

I was watching a youtube video earlier and I found two of these "조차" particles come up in the video:

- 모든 인간관계의 문제, 모든 범죄**조차**도
  저는 그 통제권을 가지려는 욕망에서 온다고 생각
  하거든요.
- 그리고 보통 이런 사람은 본인**조차**도 통제하지 못하고 있을 확률이 높습니다.

So my question is, what kind of noun usually precedes 조차, and could someone please describe why and in what situations 조차 is used? Could the sentence be used without 조차?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can think of 조차 as "even" in English.  It gives a striking example of something to suggest that lesser, more ordinary cases don't even deserve a mention. So the noun it attaches to is usually a surprising or extreme case, like "crime" in the first example and "oneself" in the second.  The person is saying even for such an unusual case as crime, the desire for control still holds as the underlying cause; and a severely affected person is likely to even fail to control themselves.

```
* 모든 인간관계의 문제, 모든 범죄조차도 저는 그 통제권을 가지려는 욕망에서 온다고 생각 하거든요.
  = (Because) I think all problems in human relations, *even* all crimes stem from this desire for control.
* 그리고 보통 이런 사람은 본인조차도 통제하지 못하고 있을 확률이 높습니다.
  = And it is very likely such a person is not *even* able to control themselves.
```

Other examples.

```
* 회사를 3년이나 다녔는데 대면 상담조차 없이 해고되었다.
  = I worked three years for the company but was let go without *even* a face-to-face meeting.
* 싸우고 난 후로 친구는 내게 눈길조차 주지 않는다.
  = After our quarrel, my friend won't *even* look in my direction.
```

Answer (score 0):

The 표준국어대사전 explains 조차 as '이미 어떤 것이 포함되고 그 위에 더함의 뜻을 나타내는 보조사. 일반적으로 예상하기 어려운 극단의 경우까지 양보하여 포함함을 나타낸다.'

That is, it already includes something and then also includes something very extreme.

I'll take the second example sentence.
A person usually 'controls' something else, belongings, one's own children, etc. It implies that controlling oneself is natural. But in the second example,  the person in the sentence cannot control him/herself.

I cannot understand the first sentence without further context.